# Sorting smallest to largest number of 3 digits input only in C++ using conditional statements

Tags: c++

My assignment is to sort the inputted 3 digits in ascending order, using conditional statements only in C++

My failed code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n1, n2, n3;
    int largest, middle, smallest;

    cin >> n1 >> n2 >> n3;

    // smallest:
    if (n1 < n2 && n1 < n3)
    {
        smallest = n1;
    }
    else if (n2 < n1 && n2 < n3)
    {
        smallest = n2;
    }
    else if (n3 < n1 && n3 < n2)
    {
        smallest = n3;
    }
        
    cout << smallest;
        
    // middle:
    if ((n1 >= n2 && n1 >= n3) && (n1 <= n2 && n1 <= n3))
    {
        middle = n1;
    }
    else if ((n2 >= n1 && n2 >= n3) && (n2 <= n1 && n2 <= n3))
    {
        middle = n2;
    }
    else if ((n3 >= n1 && n3 >= n2) && (n3 <= n1 && n3 <= n2))
    {
        middle = n3;
    }
    
    cout << " " << middle;

    // largest:
    if (n1 > n2 && n1 > n3)
    {
        largest = n1;
    }
    else if (n2 > n1 && n2 > n3)
    {
        largest = n2;
    }
    else if (n3 > n2 && n3 > n1)
    {
        largest = n3;
    }
    
    cout << " " << largest;

    return 0;
}
```

```
Input: 6 1 3
My Output: 1 0 6
Expected Output: 1 3 6
```

As you can see, I couldn't figure out how to sort the middle digit to be sorted to the middle of the 3 digits. I don't have a problem with the largest and smallest digits since I can use < and > to them, except for the middle.

Comment: Read the first number into `largest`. Then read the second number and make any movements, repeat with the third number.

Comment: How would you do it if someone gave you three playing cards?  Would you do it the way your code does now?  I think instead you would do one of 2 things: scan for the lowest card, move it to the front, then swap the last two if necessary.  Or, order the first two cards by swapping, then insert the last card into the correct location.

Comment: Are you sure numbers will be different? If not, your code will not set `smallest` nor `largest` if all three are equal.

Comment: @CiaPan Yes, I have to make sure the code knows to sort equal digits as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ((n1 >= n2 || n1 >= n3) && (n1 <= n2 || n1 <= n3))
{
    middle = n1;
}
else if ((n2 >= n1 || n2 >= n3) && (n2 <= n1 || n2 <= n3))
{
    middle = n2;
}
else if ((n3 >= n1 || n3 >= n2) && (n3 <= n1 || n3 <= n2))
{
    middle = n3;
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing serivce. An explanation of what the code does, no matter how trivial, is important. Not only that, but it is also useful to the OP *why* what they were doing was wrong.

Comment: This did answer the first problem but unfortunately this did not help entirely with or without explanation to your help.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need six variables to sort three numbers.

```
#include <algorithm>  // std::swap
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int large, middle, small;

  // Read first two numbers then arrange them accordingly
  std::cin >> large >> middle;

  if (middle > large) {
    std::swap(middle, large);
  }

  // Read final number and place accordingly
  std::cin >> small;
  if (small > large) {
    // We need two swaps because we first move the value of large to
    // to small, but now small is greater than middle, so we swap
    // those two variables.
    std::swap(small, large);
    std::swap(small, middle);
  }
  else if (small > middle) {
    std::swap(small, middle);
  }

  std::cout << small << ' ' << middle << ' ' << large << '\n';
}
```

There is no need for crazy comparisons, or lots of them *for the case of three numbers only*. Naturally if the input gets bigger we'd defenestrate this idea entirely and use an actual sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

After you find `smallest` & `largest`, `middle = n1 + n2 + n3 - largest - smallest`. (This may be vulnerable to an integer overflow, thanks for the comment.)

You can also use six if statement:

```
if(n1 >= n2 && n2 >= n3)
    max = n1, middle = n2, min = n3;
else if(n1 >= n3 && n3 >= n2)
    max = n1, middle = n3, min = n2;
// ... fill the following 4 permutations
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider an alternate approach to finding the smallest of three ints. Much cleaner. You're apparently not allowed to use loops, but the dataset is small enough that we can essentially just unroll the loop.

```cpp
int smallest_of_three(int a, int b, int c) {
    int smallest = a;

    if (b < smallest) {
        smallest = b;
    }

    if (c < smallest) {
        smallest = c;
    }

    return smallest;
}
```

We can do the same for the largest.

```cpp
int largest_of_three(int a, int b, int c) {
    int largest = a;

    if (b > largest) {
        largest = b;
    }

    if (c > largest) {
        largest = c;
    }

    return largest;
}
```

We can then use these to find the middle by checking to see if each of a, b, and c are not either the smallest or largest. A default case of returning `a`  handles the case where there are duplicates.

```cpp
int middle_of_three(int a, int b, int c) {
    int s = smallest_of_three(a, b, c);
    int l = largest_of_three(a, b, c);

    if (a != s && a != l) {
        return a;
    }
    else if (b != s && b != l) {
        return b;
    }
    else if (c != s && b != l) {
        return c;
    }
    else {
        return a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer, just using the if statements.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n1, n2, n3;

    cin >> n1 >> n2 >> n3;
        if (n1 <= n2 && n1 <= n3)
        {
            cout << n1 << " ";
                if (n2 <= n3)
                {
                    cout << n2 << " " << n3;
                }
                else if (n3 <= n2)
                {
                    cout << n3 << " " << n2;
                }
        }
        else if (n2 <= n1 && n2 <= n3)
        {
            cout << n2 << " ";
                if (n1 <= n3)
                {
                    cout << n1 << " " << n3;
                }
                else if (n3 <= n1)
                {
                    cout << n3 << " " << n1;
                }
        }
        else if (n3 <= n1 && n3 <= n2)
        {
            cout << n3 << " ";
                if (n1 <= n2)
                {
                    cout << n1 << " " << n2;
                }
                else if (n2 <= n1)
                {
                    cout << n2 << " " << n1;
                }
        }
}
```

No further explanation needed, everything is self explanatory i.e., using the conditional if statements.